# Creating a dynanic form in AngularJS with nested lists

Tags: angularjs

I have a model in AngularJS that is structured like so:

```
region = { 'substances': [ 
{ 'id': 123, 'name': 'Hello', 'versions': ['A', 'B', 'C'] }, 
{ 'id': 456, 'name': 'World', 'versions': ['A', 'B', 'C'] } 
]}
```

I want to be able to display and modify this model in a form.  Currently I have nested ng-repeats:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="substance in region.substances">
        <input name="substance[]" class="input-medium" type="text" ng-model="substance.name">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="version in substance.versions">
                <input style="margin-left: 10px;" type="text" name="<% substance.id %>.version[]" class="input-medium" ng-model="version">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(Note: I've redefined AngularJS brackets to be <% %>).

I can modify the name, but I AngularJS prevents me from even typing in the inner inputs.  I'm guessing that I'm not binding to the model correctly?  Also, how would I go about adding another "substance" that has a name and a list of versions?

Is there a proper way to be naming my inputs?

Comment: I guess changing the list of versions from literals to objects would greatly ease things here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you named the inputs, I guess this is a problem with Angular, because It is not binding correctly. Check this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iwoqek/6/edit) to see that the binding works when we point to the parent attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Yoshi , is always easiest to use object inheritance rather than primitive within nested scopes.

```
 $scope.region = { substances: [ 
  { name: 'Hello', versions: [{x:'A'},{x: 'B'},{x: 'C'}] }, 
  { name: 'World', versions: [{x:'A'},{x: 'B'},{x: 'C'}] } 
]};
```

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="substance in region.substances">
    <input class="input-medium" type="text" ng-model="substance.name">
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="version in substance.versions">
       <input type="text" ng-model="version.x">
     </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/p5utTb0AcyXxs8w6HGVa?p=preview)</kbd>